# Using Alloy widget in Appcelerator project

Tags: widget, appcelerator, appcelerator-alloy

I just found a website from where I can get alloy widgets http://alloylove.com/

Please tell me how to use/integrate downloaded widgets in my project.

Comment: Be aware that that said hasn't been [updated](https://github.com/joshjensen/alloylove.com) for 3 years.

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://gitt.io/ instead of http://alloylove.com/  , because `gitt.io` can install `widgets` `modules` for you .

For example :-   to install `nl.fokkezb.loading` widget  http://gitt.io/component/nl.fokkezb.loading from your project root  run this command

```
$ gittio install nl.fokkezb.loading
```

It`s easy .

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the contents and put it inside the widget folder. Once that is done, update the config.json file. Once done, call createWidget call and you are good to go.